# JMS threads stuck in proxyMQGET on Websphere com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteProxyQueue.proxyMQGET

Tags: multithreading, performance, websphere, ibm-mq, spring-jms

My application is running on Websphere 9 and interacting with IBM MQ and Oracle. I am facing an issue with high queue depth on a certain queue. I checked for bottlenecks in my process and found in the AWR report one insert query that was taking around a minute. This would explain the low throughput and high queue depth. However, I could also see some hung JMS threads in the server logs. These threads seem to be stuck for 15-16 minutes while waiting to receive a message. Below are the stack traces for two of these threads, others also have the same. I am having a hard time figuring out the root cause as there isn't much information available related to this in application logs. There aren't any "MQCC" errors.

```
[11/30/21 11:45:05:670 GMT] 00000096 ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "WorkManager.JMSWorkManager : 56" (0000068c) has been active for 961315 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 3 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:218)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteProxyQueue.proxyMQGET(RemoteProxyQueue.java:2460)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiGetInternalWithRecon(RemoteFAP.java:6334)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiGetInternal(RemoteFAP.java:6233)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.internal.JmqiTools.getMessage(JmqiTools.java:1192)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiGet(RemoteFAP.java:6194)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.getMsg(WMQConsumerShadow.java:1440)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSyncConsumerShadow.receiveInternal(WMQSyncConsumerShadow.java:235)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.receive(WMQConsumerShadow.java:1194)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.receive(WMQMessageConsumer.java:460)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl.receiveInboundMessage(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:817)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl.receive(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:501)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageConsumer.receive(MQMessageConsumer.java:212)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSMessageConsumerHandle.receive(JMSMessageConsumerHandle.java:553)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSMessageConsumerHandle.receive(JMSMessageConsumerHandle.java:501)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JmsDestinationAccessor.receiveFromConsumer(JmsDestinationAccessor.java:132)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveMessage(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:418)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:303)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:245)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1189)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.DelegatingWork.run(DelegatingWork.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$RunProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:267)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:704)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:490)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:133)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$DoAsProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:338)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:734)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:1174)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.go(WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.java:199)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.CJWorkItemImpl.run(CJWorkItemImpl.java:237)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
[11/30/21 11:45:05:671 GMT] 00000096 ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "WorkManager.JMSWorkManager : 50" (000005f1) has been active for 901025 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 4 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:218)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.queueRequest(FreePool.java:441)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1342)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3907)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3085)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1554)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1033)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryHandle.createConnection(JMSConnectionFactoryHandle.java:256)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:196)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.access$100(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer$MessageListenerContainerResourceFactory.createConnection(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:490)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalSession(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:325)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:281)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:245)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1189)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.DelegatingWork.run(DelegatingWork.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$RunProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:267)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:704)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:490)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:133)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$DoAsProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:338)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:734)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:1174)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.go(WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.java:199)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.CJWorkItemImpl.run(CJWorkItemImpl.java:237)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

Comment: Are there messages that the thread **should** have got but didn't in that 15 minute time period? How long are your get wait intervals on your applications. If they are **supposed** to wait for 15 minutes or more before giving up on messages arriving, then this doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: @MoragHughson, the wait time is configured as 60 secs. <property name="receiveTimeout" value="60000"/>

Comment: And are there messages sitting on the queues that these getting thread should have processed and didn't?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I am also stuck with a similar issue.